# Check python numpy array contains numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I want to check if a numpy array contains only elements that are numbers. So any type of integer or float. I don't care what type of integer or float they are.

Comment: What's the array `dtype`?

Comment: @hpaulj that's the point. I don't know. I want to see if it is any type of integer or float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```py
>>> data = np.array([1, 1.2, 0])
>>> data.dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> np.issubdtype(data.dtype, np.number)
True
>>> data = np.array([1, 1, 0])
>>> data.dtype
dtype('int32')
>>> np.issubdtype(data.dtype, np.number)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `array.dtype` and comparing it to `float` or `int`.

```py
import numpy as np

array = np.zeros(1)

array.dtype == float
>>> True

array.dtype == int
>>> False
```

Answer (score 0):

If suppose it depends if you're wanting to call `1.0` and integer due to it being a whole number, or a float due to it being stored as a floating point number.

If you're wanting the former then you could do, e.g.:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
# check if integers
print(np.all([float(val).is_integer() for val in x]))
True
```